# Derivative of a vector that is dot producted with another vector?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus

If I have the following function: $a\textbf{x}$ , where $a$ and $\textbf{x}$ are both vectors that I am taking the dot product between, how can I differentiate this function with respect to $\textbf{x}$? What about the 2nd derivative?

For a concrete example, let's assume `a = [1, 2, 3]` and $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ (I think this is the correct terminology to say that $\textbf{x}$ can be any vector of length 3 that is made up of real numbers?).

I'm asking because on Math Stack Exchange I see many complicated examples, and I just need some intuition about the very basics.

Comment: What is your definition of the derivative?

Comment: @JacobManaker  I'm not aware there were multiple definitions. Mostly, I have a function that takes in a vector, $v$, from $\mathbb{R}^3$ and turns it into a scalar, through a series of dot products / matrix multiplies. I'm trying to prove the function is convex, which involves showing that the 2nd derivative is non-negative for all $x$. So whatever definition of a derivative will satisfy that.

Comment: if $x$ is a function of a real variable $t$ then :
$$\left(a \cdot x\right)' = a \cdot x'(t)$$

Comment: @Essaidi $\textbf{x}$ is just a vector that is an input to the function. It is not a function of anything else.

Comment: For the first derivative, consider this sequence operations
$$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\l = a\cdot x \qiq d\l = a\cdot dx \qiq \g{\l}{x} = a
$$ Since $a$ is constant, its derivative is zero, so
$\;{\large \g{^2\l}{x^2} = \g{a}{x} = 0}\:$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $a\cdot \textbf{x}$ with respect to $\textbf{x}$ is
$$
\left({\partial\over dx},{\partial\over dy}\right)a\cdot \textbf{x}=(a_x,a_y).
$$
It is not so very different than the derivative of $f(x)=cx$, ${d\over dx}f(x)=c$.